# Minecraft LAN only works half the time

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Half the time when my brother and I are trying to connect to each other's world it works fine, but the other half of the time when he does it it simply waits on

`"Connecting to server"`

until it says:

`"javan.net.ConnectException: timed out no further information:"`

and I can never find his server.

Comment: What OS are both of you using?  If both of you are on the same LAN, are either of you using Wifi?  Other than the 1 main router for your LAN, is there any other hardware either of you are connected to (switch, second router's wifi, etc.)?  If you know the address to connect to, have you tried to ping it when you can't connect?  My assumption is either some hardware isn't working right, or more likely the computer lost connection to your brother's computer (or vise-versa).  If you ping and it times out, then it's a connection problem, if it works, there's settings that need changed.

Answer (score 1):

I used to never be able to do lan. Same error but I *always* got it.
We just turned off the firewall on the host machine and it worked.
If you are running the server from a different computer, it might work only sometimes because of different firewall settings.

Answer (score -3):

LAN is notoriously bad for playing together on a world as the error you have experienced happens more times than LAN actually works. Another way to play with your brother is to use a website hosting, or the server tool provided by Minecraft.

To use MCProHosting, check out this tutorial:

To use the server tool, check out this tutorial: